# Манипуляции с url изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Понравился метод оформления картинок на [странице](http://www.stroitelstvosovety.ru/landshaftnyy-dizayn/ukladka-trotuarnoj-plitki-svoimi-rukami)

С помощью jquery сумел таки каждый `img` поместить внутри дива и задал диву класс.

Но вот как теперь получать `url` картинок и добавлять его в качестве бэкграунда для созданного дива?

Comment: Сделайте это на стороне сервера.

Comment: тоже через jQuery, у img получаете аттрибут src и вставляете значение как фон

Comment: Я это понимаю. Просто не владею этим языком. Какие именно строки кода для этого использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать такой эффект и на CSS, без особого использования jQuery. Но если понимания, как вы сказали, не очень много, то попробуйте посмотреть в сторону уже готовых решений, например jQuery-плагин http://www.blurjs.com/ (требует наличия jQuery). Сначала подключаете jQuery, затем уже плагин. И пробуете примеры кода со страницы плагина.